How can I resolve the "No ReaderType or WriterType could be detected" issue when importing an Excel file from S3 to a web server using PHP?
I am getting this issue on excel file import on web server. But this is working fine on local server.
No ReaderType or WriterType could be detected. Make sure you either pass a valid extension to the filename or pass an explicit type.
code i have used:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\SettingRequest;
use App\Imports\DriverImport;
use App\Imports\OrderImport;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class S3Controller extends Controller
{
    public function importFile(SettingRequest $request)
    {
        $importType = $request->input('import_type');
        $dispatcherId = $request->input('dispatcher_id');
        $filePath = $request->input('file_path'); // S3 file path

        if ($importType === 'driver') {
            $import = new DriverImport($dispatcherId);
        } elseif ($importType === 'order') {
            $import = new OrderImport($dispatcherId);
            DB::table('orders')->truncate();
            // DB::table('orderassignemts')->truncate();
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid import type'], 400);
        }

        try {
            // Download file from S3
            $s3 = new S3Client([
                'version' => 'latest',
                'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
                'credentials' => [
                    'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
                ],
                'http' => [
                    'verify' => false,
                ],
            ]);

            $result = $s3->getObject([
                'Bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
                'Key' => $filePath,
            ]);

            $fileContent = $result['Body']->getContents();
            $tempFilePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'import_'); 
            file_put_contents($tempFilePath, $fileContent);

            // Process the Excel data and save it to the database

            Excel::import($import, $tempFilePath);
            $rowsProcessed = $import->getRowCount();
            $rowsskipped = $import->getRowsSkipped();
            $skippedRowNumber = $import->getSkippedRows();

            unlink($tempFilePath);

            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Data processed successfully',
                'Rows_processed' => $rowsProcessed,
                'Rows_Skipped' => $rowsskipped,
                'Rows' => $skippedRowNumber,
            ]);
        } catch (S3Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }
}

Please help to resolve this issue.
I Tried this
Excel::import($import, $tempFilePath, null, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);


but i dont want to Explicitly Specify File Type.
